# WebRTC VideoCall Rendering in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, webrtc, swiftui

i am using webRTC for video call between two iphone devices. The webrtc peer connection is established successfully. The video stream should show in swiftui. The webRTC object RTCEAGLVideoView that holds the video need to render in swiftui. In the model class i declared this object as

```
var remoteVideoView : RTCEAGLVideoView?
    {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
```

in the SwiftUI class, the remoteVideoView should render.

```
VStack()
{
//show remoteVideoView  here
}
```

what kind of object should use to render this videoview.

Code in short[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcr0Q.png)

Comment: could you please explain your question precisely. This is not clear what exactly you want. Please edit might be someone can help!

Comment: Ok, You want to render local video or remote video.

Comment: I want to render remote video

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create `RTCMediaStream` which contains audio tracks and video tracks:

```
@property RTCMediaStream * _Nullable mediaStream;
```

The streams which you are getting from your media server with streamId convert those into `RTCMediaStream` and then use the below code to render it in `RTCEAGLVideoView`

```
 if (mediaStream.videoTracks.count > 0) {
     RTCVideoTrack *videoTrack = [self.mediaStream.videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];
     [videoTrack addRenderer:remoteView];
   }
```

Also Create a IBOutlet of RTCEAGLVideoView like below:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RTCEAGLVideoView *remoteView;
```

Now Add a view in your view controller and assign class as `RTCEAGLVideoView` to that view. Next connect the videoView outlet.

In case you are not using storyboard use below code:

```
 RTCEAGLVideoView *remoteView = [[RTCEAGLVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]; // pass CGRect frame here.
 remoteView.delegate = self;
 [yourView addSubview:remoteView];
```

Now you can see your video.

Add RTCEAGLVideoView in VStack() use below:

```
struct RemoteView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func remoteView(context: Context) -> RTCEAGLVideoView {
        //create frame for RTCEAGLVideoView here
    }
}


struct RemoteView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RemoteView(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

In VStack use like:

```
 VStack {
          RemoteView(frame)
      VStack{
           Text("")
           }
       }
```

Comment: func webrtcClient(client : WebRtcClient, didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack)
    {
        // Use remoteVideoTrack generated for rendering stream to remoteVideoView
        remoteVideoTrack.add(self.remoteVideoView!)
        self.remoteVideoTrack = remoteVideoTrack
    }. I have this code in model class. from there i am publishing 'remoteVideoView' like var remoteVideoView : RTCEAGLVideoView?
    {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }. how to display this object 'remoteVideoView' in swiftui

Comment: Edited my answer check and hope you are using Storyboards.

Comment: Am using SwiftUI and created all the View components using stack, button etc, it is not possible to show the video without storyboards.  I am not using Storyboard

Comment: VStack()
               {
                    Text("VIDEO   CALL")  //Show Video in this block
                }

Comment: did you try the solution?

Comment: no. i am trying to implement inside the VStack(). As i mentioned remoteVideoView is available in swiftui class. But i don't know how to display inside the VStack() in swiftUI. Currently i am not used storyboard in my project. If i am not able to display inside VStack then i have to choose storyboard option. So i can assume, using SwiftUI, we can't show RTCEAGLVideoView

Comment: I don't think so that you can't show RTCEAGLVideoView. It as simple as you are adding other views in your VStack() . Add RTCEAGLVideoView in the same way you added other views and try. Could you please add VStack() code.

Comment: Check this to add custom views in VStack. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views

Comment: @ctoplatform Check my updated answer if it helps you.

Comment: i am getting compiler error while trying to call RemoteView() from VStack

Comment: else if(isVideoCall)
                            {
                                
                                VStack()
                                    {
//                                        Text("Video Call")
                                        RemoteView()
                                }
                              
                            } i am getting error as "'(LocalizedStringKey) -> Text' is not convertible to '(LocalizedStringKey, String?, Bundle?, StaticString?) -> Text'.  if i comment RemoteView(), it will compile successfully.

Comment: what if you comment Text("Video Call") and only use RemoteView(), please try and let me know.

Comment: Same error after commenting Text("Video Call"). Am calling RemoteView() inside VStack(). I believe that RemoteView() is having some issues.

Comment: can you try like this  VStack {
          RemoteView(frame)
      VStack{
           Text("Video Call").
           }
       }

Comment: i added pic of code. i am not setting any frame while calling RemoteView(). Text("Video call") line is optional and i don;t need Text("Video Call")

Comment: i am done using uiviewcontroller in swift and not used swiftui

Answer (score 1):

```
struct RemoteView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var video: VideoCall
    @Binding var remoteView: RTCEAGLVideoView
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: RTCEAGLVideoView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<RemoteView>) {
   }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCEAGLVideoView  {
        self.remoteView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 300)
        self.remoteView = self.video.remoteVideoView!
        return self.remoteView
    }

}
```

I called this from another swiftui struct as

```
VStack()
{ 
      RemoteView() 
}
```

but i am getting compiler error

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIViewRepresentable** to use your RTCEAGLVideoView in SwiftUI. I've added a sample code that uses RTCMTLVideoView instead of RTCEAGLVideoView, however, you can replace it.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebRTC

struct RendererView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var track: RTCVideoTrack?
    
    let videoContentMode: UIView.ContentMode
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCMTLVideoView {
        let videoView = RTCMTLVideoView()
        videoView.contentMode = videoContentMode
        return videoView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: RTCMTLVideoView, context: Context) {
        guard let track = track else {
            return
        }
        track.add(uiView)
    }
}
```

You can use [WebRTC-Demo-SwiftUI](https://github.com/kuttz/webrtc_demo_swiftui) code for reference.